# Alternative for @javascriptinterface in react-native for webview addjavascriptinterface()

Tags: react-native

I want to implement one of my existing project into react-native, project having webview where the page is loaded and after page loading there are few methods which are invoked at my native end with the help of:

```
 @javascriptbridge (webview.addJavaScriptInterface(bridge,"Android").
```

Now, want to do same in react native , i have already tried WebViewBridge lib but i am getting problem in using that as unable to resolve:

```
"import WebViewBridge from 'react-native-webview-bridge'
```

I have also used invoke like (onMessage={this.invoke.listener}) and invoke.define("myMethod",myMethod) but still my method is not called after page loads.

Can you please help me!

Comment: Could you post more code? onMessage should work but it has some caveats need to take care.

Comment: i think after staring the bounty they disabled edit question option in this..------>>>>>invoke = createInvoke(() => this.webview); 
componentDidMount(){
            this.invoke
                .define('CartCount', this.CartCount)
                .define('page', this.page)
                .define('UserSessionCheck', this.UserSessionCheck);
        }

Comment: This is the code i have written to call my methods, and in <WebView> i have define onMessage = this.invoke.listener

Comment: You should not send the data immediately, you should use a `setTimeout` and then send the data. See the example https://blog.bigbinary.com/2016/05/25/send-receive-data-between-react-native-and-webview.html